# Attemp to invoke interface method java.lang.String com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap ... on a null object reference

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, storage

I'm getting this error after uploading image to firebase storage. I am using
"react-native": "0.55.4",
"react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
"react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.10",
"firebase": "^5.0.4",

this is my code for uploading the image.

```
// Prepare Blob support
const Blob = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob;

const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;
window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest;
window.Blob = Blob;

uploadImage = (uri, imageName, mime = "image/jpg") => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const uploadUri =
        Platform.OS === "ios" ? uri.replace("file://", "") : uri;
      let uploadBlob = null;
      const imageRef = db
        .storage()
        .ref("images/")
        .child(imageName);

  fs.readFile(uploadUri, "base64")
    .then(data => {
      return Blob.build(data, { type: `${mime};BASE64` });
    })
    .then(blob => {
      uploadBlob = blob;
      alert("blob is " + JSON.stringify(blob));
      return imageRef.put(blob, { contentType: mime });
    })
    .then(() => {
      uploadBlob.close();
      return imageRef.getDownloadURL();
    })
    .then(url => {
      resolve(url);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      reject(error);
    });
});};
```

Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference readAsText     FileReaderModule.java:43 invoke     Method.java invoke     JavaMethodWrapper.java:372 invoke     JavaModuleWrapper.java:160 run     NativeRunnable.java handleCallback     Handler.java:790 dispatchMessage     Handler.java:99 dispatchMessage     MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29 loop     Looper.java:164 run     MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192 run     Thread.java:764

Comment: Please add the full error to the question

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same error. The solution is to do a 'Fetch replacement' as the official documentation explains:

> Since we are not implementing FileReader polyfill, you might run into
>   this error in some cases.
>
> If you're facing this problem with Blob polyfill in Debug Mode, try
>   replace window.fetch with fetch replacement should fix it.

And:

> If you have existing code that uses whatwg-fetch, now you don't have
>   to change existing code after 0.9.0, just use fetch replacement. The
>   difference between Official fetch and fetch replacement is that,
>   official fetch uses WHATWG-fetch js library which wraps XMLHttpRequest
>   polyfill under the hood, and our implementation simply wraps
>   RNFetchBlob.fetch.

Basically, you just have to add this to your code, just below your `window.Blob = Blob;` line:

```
const Fetch = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Fetch
// replace built-in fetch
window.fetch = new Fetch({
    // enable this option so that the response data conversion handled automatically
    auto : true,
    // when receiving response data, the module will match its Content-Type header
    // with strings in this array. If it contains any one of string in this array, 
    // the response body will be considered as binary data and the data will be stored
    // in file system instead of in memory.
    // By default, it only store response data to file system when Content-Type 
    // contains string `application/octet`.
    binaryContentTypes : [
        'image/',
        'video/',
        'audio/',
        'foo/',
    ]
}).build()
```

Documentation:
https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#failed-to-execute-readastext-on-filereader

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Hi Paul, i'm new to StackOverflow so thank you so much for the feedback. I'm going to edit my answer and take that into account for future answers.